# Showing $\frac1{n^3}\sum_{1\leq a\leq n\\ (a,n)=1}{a^3}=\frac{\phi(n)}4(1+\frac{(-1)^k{p_1\cdots p_k}}{n^2})$, with $p_i$ the prime factors of $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to prove the following identity involving Euler's Totient Function.

$$\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{1\leq a\leq n \\ (a,n)=1} {a^3} \;=\; {\frac{\phi(n)}{4}}\left(1+{\frac{{(-1)^k}{p_1\cdots p_k}}{n^2}}\right)$$

where $p_1....p_k$ are the distinct prime factors of $n$.

The RHS suggests that the Mobius Function may be involved.

Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it is straight application of Moebius inversion on both sides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start with $$\sum_{ {a=1}\\{(n,a)=1}}^{n}a^N=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)d^N\sum_{k=1}^{n/d}k^N$$
where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function.
For $n>1$ and $N=3$
$$\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{ {a=1}\\{(n,a)=1}}^{n}a^3=\frac{\phi(n)}{4}+\frac{\phi^{-1}(n)}{4n}$$
where $\phi(n)=\sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}\mu(d)$ is the totient function and $\phi^{-1}(n)=\sum_{d|n}d\mu(d)$ is the inverse totient function.
By substitution
$$\phi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}\frac{p-1}{p}$$ and
$$\phi^{-1}(n)=\prod_{p|n}(1-p)$$
you wil get the desired result.

Comment: perfect, I was going to look for those convolutions right now. This should do it.